# Convert SQL query result into two dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to using PHP and MySQL, and I am looking to run a calculation in PHP using a variable that I retrieve from a API / data-feed in JSON and other variables stores in a table within my database.

Here is the code to retrieve my variable from a JSON file. This works fine:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://gold-feed.com/paid/API....php');
$XAUGBP = json_decode($json);
$XAUGBP = $XAUGBP->gold_bid_gbp_toz;
```

Then I have the following tables in my database:

```
               TABLE 1                                  TABLE 2

id | product | weight(gr) | margin | fee               id | bafa

 1    Kilo       1000        1.03    20£                1    3£
 2    500G       500         1.04    20£
 3    250G       250         1.05    20£
...   ...        ...         ...     ...
```

The calculation is really simple. I start by adding `bafa` from TABLE 2 to $XAUGBP and transforming it to grams:

```
($XAUGBP + bafa) / 31.1035

Example:
(960 + 3) / 31.1035
= 963 / 31.1035
= 30.96£
```

Then I have to use this result to run the calculation as a loop for all the rows, using the data from TABLE 1:

```
$result = 30.96£ * weight * margin + fee
```

I don't know if I should convert the entire table into a two-dimensional array or use `mysqli_query` to store each parameters into a variable.

How should I do it? What would you recommend to write that?

Comment: your table 2 contains a £ currency in bafa column?

Comment: Philippe Emond : no it's just an integer (3). I mentioned the (£) because the result after calculation has to be a price in pound £.